# How to seal seams in a traditional Cedar wood dry sauna

Tags: hvac, sealant

I just built a new, indoor, traditional  dry sauna made with Cedar wood.

https://www.costco.com/almost-heaven-bluestone-3-person-steam-sauna.product.100485086.html

During assembly, some of the creases did not fit together perfectly, leaving me with very small ( < 1cm ) seams at two of the top corners. I suspect this may be preventing the sauna from heating to its advertised maximum of 180-200 degrees F.

The gaps are too small for shims. Maybe HVAC tape? I considered caulk but I'm not sure how "safe" that solution would be at high temperatures.

Any tips on sealing these?

Comment: The gaps ( "*creases*" ) you are referring to are  at the junctions of the pre-made panels ? If so i would suggest you re-assemble it in order to make the proper connections.

Comment: Yeah, I'm beyond attempting to disassemble and make minor modifications at this point. It was traumatic enough to get it assembled.

Comment: I’m not sure that Jerry rigging something that was not put together properly in the first place is going to give you the results that you need. You could try to stuff some fiberglass insulation into the gaps and see if that stops the heat loss.